# PowerShell - WinGet - Compare Available Package Version to Currently installed

Tags: powershell, intune, winget

Currently working with WinGet to improve application deployment lifecycle within Intune.
I am looking at deploying a detection script that checks for the installed version daily, then triggers the remediation if there is an available update.

Doing something as simple as:

```
winget list --name 7-Zip
```

will return as follows:

```
Name              Id        Version Available Source
----------------------------------------------------
7-Zip 19.00 (x64) 7zip.7zip 19.00   22.01     winget
```

Within Powershell, is there a way we can check and compare the Available "*column*" to the Version "*column*", and return an exit 0 or exit 1?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to know is *whether or not* an upgrade is available, to be reflected in the script's exit code:

The following reports exit code `1` if an upgrade *is* available, and `0` otherwise, relying on an `Available` column header only being present if an upgrade is available:

```bash
exit [int] (winget list --name 7-Zip | Select-String '\bVersion\s+Available\b' -Quiet)
```

---

If you also want to report the installed vs. the latest available version, more work is needed:

```bash
$name = '7-Zip'
$lines = winget list --name $name
if ($lines -match '\bVersion\s+Available\b') {
  $verinstalled, $verAvailable = (-split $lines[-1])[-3,-2]
  [pscustomobject] @{
    Name = $name
    InstalledVersion = [version] $verInstalled
    AvailableVersion = [version] $verAvailable
  }
  exit 1
} else {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "No upgrade for $name available."
  exit 0
}
```

The above outputs something like the following if an upgrade is available; the exit code is set as in the first command:

```bash
Name    InstalledVersion AvailableVersion
----    ---------------- ----------------
7-Zip   9.0.30729.4148   9.0.30729.6161
```

---

Alternatively, if it's acceptable to *blindly try to upgrade*:

```bash
winget upgrade --name 7-Zip --silent
# If $LASTEXITCODE contains -1978335189, an upgrade was NOT available.
```

Comment: This works amazingly, I appreciate the support. 
Only thing thats been noticed is if the application has multiple spaces, such as Adobe Acrobat DC, the Split needs to be amended by the seems of things. Is this a correct observation?

Comment: @Batteredburrito, it's fine for the `Name` column value to have spaces. You'd only have a problem if the `Source` column value had spaces.  The preinstalled source (`winget`, `msstore`, determined via`winget source list`) do _not_. Do you have / know of sources that do (I'm asking innocently)?

Comment: Got it, thanks so much for the prompt answer, really helped me out on this one. Marking as solved

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Batteredburrito; my pleasure. Thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

`winget upgrade`

it will return available upgrades

like

```
Name                                                      Id                                    Version          Available     Source
Google Chrome                                             Google.Chrome                         103.0.5060.53    104.0.5112.81 winget
Microsoft Edge                                            Microsoft.Edge                        103.0.1264.49    104.0.1293.47 winget
```

Comment: Doing the upgrade command will list all apps on system and their relevant updates.
For my use case, individual app updates are checked and remediated which offers more granularity.

I am okay with either method, but still need to resolve the exit codes